# Arbitrary Warping of Object Image Shapes

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision

I am looking for a way to take any arbitrary shaped object and warp it into another arbitrary shape.

I have looked at OpenCV's methods for finding homographies and such, but I am not sure whether something like this exists or where to look.

Here is an example of what I want to do. I want to be able to take in a face like this:
[Face image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFlEY.jpg)
And I want to be able to warp that face into a different shape, say like this: [Blob shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FBS7.jpg)

I can do this in image editing programs. I see two problems. The first problem is how to know which points on the face image should be assigned to what points on the arbitrary blob image. Secondarily, how to do the warping? I suppose this could be done using `cv2.remap` or something like that? Another idea was something like TensorFlow's `sparse_image_warp` but I am not sure that would allow me to do arbitrary shapes like this.